# Ler cookie["PAI"]["FILHO"] em PHP

Tags: php

Preciso ler em PHP um cookie existente, criado em asp classico.

```
<% Response.Cookies("PAI")("FILHO") %>
```

tentei ler em PHP desta forma abaixo e não deu certo, por favor me ajudem

```
<?php
if ( isset($_COOKIE["PAI"]["FILHO"] )) {
    $valor = $_COOKIE["PAI"]["FILHO"];
}
else{
    $valor = 0;
}
echo "cookie: ".$valor;
?>
```

Comment: Por quê não deu certo? Qual é o resultado de `var_dump($_COOKIE)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui fazendo da seguinte forma

```
if ( isset($_COOKIE["PAI"] )) {    
    $valor = $_COOKIE["PAI"];
    $items = explode("FILHO=", $valor);

    print_r($items);
    RESULTADO DO PRINT_R [
      Array
      (
      [0] => prevlogoff=23/03/2018 13:08:10&dtacesso=23-03-2018 07:08:10&
      [1] => 1
      )
    ]

    echo "01)".$items[1];
}
else{
    echo 0;
}
```

Sei que poderia ter utilizado "&" no explode, porém desta forma obtive o resultado que eu precisava.
Obrigado Galera!